# Mongo: "exception: connect failed"

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to connect to the mongo server, using the "mongo" command in the command prompt and this error is showing: "exception: connect failed"

Here is how I am trying to do it:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin>mongo
MongoDB shell version v3.4.7

connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017

2017-08-10T23:19:22.708-0600 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.

2017-08-10T23:19:22.708-0600 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :

connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
```

Here is an image:
[image: img]

Please, be nice, I am a begginer and I dont know a lot from this technology.

Comment: Make sure that your mongo is running??? The above error states that your Mongo process is not running..

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: Also can you check if there are any log files in your mongo log

Answer (score 0):

This error occur when your client try to connect server and it could not connect into connection-timeout time, and it takes more time to connect. first check your `mongo` server is properly running or not and also check the the port no which you are using. check your `firewall` also, may be firewall blocking the request in `port` which you are using into your server.

Answer (score -1):

create folder named **db** under **data** folder in C drive for database

default database folder for mongodb is **C:\data\db**